# Need Help Identifying 90s Ninja Anime

Tags: ninku

I remember watching an anime in Japan in the 90s. It was ninja themed, where I believe the protagonist was a rather smaller ninja and one of his move was to make a "ball" using his palm and slamming it directly against an enemy. Anyone happen to know what the name of this anime is?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm maybe... **[Ninku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninku)**?
The protagonist is "rather smaller ninja".
And in this pic he does "make a "ball" using his palm" and seems like he will throw it.
[image: Ninku]